# Want duplicated results in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been given a list of 10,000+ IDs with some duplicates that I would like displayed in the results.

For example, I would like the results of the query `select * from table where id in (1,2,2,3,4)` to displayed like the following:

```
id | name | desc
----------------
1  | Abe  | name
2  | Bell | symp
2  | Bell | symp
3  | Cat  | anim
4  | Dan  | name
```

Comment: Just `SELECT *` will return all data from a table including duplicates.  Do you have a real table, then a list of `id`s?  In that case, populate a table with the list of `id`s, then `JOIN` to the main table.  If the `id` is duplicated in the list, it will duplicate in the results.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

If you like typing, you could to do this using `join`.  This is easy with a derived table:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select 1 as id union all
      select 2 as id union all
      select 2 as id union all
      select 3 as id union all
      select 4 as id 
     ) i
     on i.id = t.id;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've added more detail in the original post. The lists consists of over 10,000 IDs

Comment: Put that list in a (temporary) table.